# Upgrading RAD JDK Version to 1.6

Tags: eclipse, java, java-6

I am using RAD for development. For my application i need to upgrade my JDK compliance to 1.6 from 1.4. I have installed jdk 1.6 and added it to my installed JRE's. Now in the JDK compliance still 1.4 is shown, what should be done to set the JDK compliance to 1.6?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Deena

Answer (score 2):

This should be set either in the global preferences, or in the properties of the project, in the "Java compiler" section:

[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/2482/eclipsejdkcompliance.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/2482/eclipsejdkcompliance.png)

See also this [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0410_mah-ho/index.html) with a section dedicated to "Modifying JDK compliance level".

Comment: Hi Von, Thanks for the response! I tried to add my 1.6 jdk version to installed jre's and then checked whether java compiler shows 1.6 in the compliance drop down, but it didnt. I got a doubt, my ecplise has 2 default java compilers 1.3 and 1.4 is it possible for me to add a new compiler to this list, i read somewhere that ecplise will always use its own default compilers for compiling, can you clarify me on this.

Comment: @Deena: what version of RAD are you using?